# What is the least amount of code needed to update one list with another list?

Tags: c#, generics, merge, generic-list

Suppose I have one list:

```
IList<int> originalList = new List<int>();
originalList.add(1);
originalList.add(5);
originalList.add(10);
```

And another list...

```
IList<int> newList = new List<int>();
newList.add(1);
newList.add(5);
newList.add(7);  
newList.add(11);
```

How can I update originalList so that:

1. If the int appears in newList, keep
2. If the int does not appear in newList, remove
3. Add any ints from newList into originalList that aren't there already

Thus - making the contents of originalList:

```
{ 1, 5, 7, 11 }
```

The reason I'm asking is because I have an object with a collection of children. When the user updates this collection, instead of just deleting all children, then inserting their selections, I think it would be more efficient if I just acted on the children that were added or removed, rather than tearing down the whole collection, and inserting the newList children as if they are all new.

EDIT - Sorry - I wrote a horrible title... I should have written 'least amount of code' instead of 'efficient'. I think that threw off alot of the answers I've gotten. They are all great... thank you!

Comment: How much time is your application spending copying values?

Comment: Can there be duplicate values? e.g. { 1, 5, 5, 7, 11 }

Comment: By the way, if you're using NHibernate and dealing with nonduplicate entities, you may want to be using Iesi.Collections.ISet<T>, not IList<T>.  ISet<T> enforces having no duplicates.

Comment: @rick - No, I don't want duplicate values.

Comment: @Kyralessa - Yes, this is the precise reason I'm writing this question - it all comes back to nhibernate. I'm passing in a parent along with its child as JSON to my codebehind. Because it is serialized without a 'parent' property on the child, I need to assign it in .NET manually. :( Hence, this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, wrote my first response before I saw your last paragraph.

```
for(int i = originalList.length-1; i >=0; --i)
{
     if (!newList.Contains(originalList[i])
            originalList.RemoveAt(i);
}

foreach(int n in newList)
{
     if (!originaList.Contains(n))
           originalList.Add(n);
}
```

Comment: Yeppers, this is exactly what I needed.. I needed the 'unchanged' answers to stay the same. So I learned two things today, oldList = newList merges them and is super sweet.. however, this answer is exactly what I needed, and has a good amount less code than what I had for my initial solution! thanks

Comment: Note that this is an O(n*n) complex method (regarded the Contains call is O(n) )

Comment: Note that after merging with the algorithm above, the items order in `OriginalList` will not necessarily match the order in `NewList`.

Answer (score 5):

```
originalList = newList;
```

Or if you prefer them being distinct lists:

```
originalList = new List<int>(newList);
```

But, either way does what you want.  By your rules, after updating, originalList will be identical to newList.

UPDATE: I thank you all for the support of this answer, but after a closer reading of the question, I believe my other response (below) is the correct one.

Comment: I'm going to kill myself if its that simple. I will add this to my code and see!

Comment: It is still too early on Monday morning ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you use some LINQ extension methods, you can do it in two lines:

```
originalList.RemoveAll(x => !newList.Contains(x));
originalList.AddRange(newList.Where(x => !originalList.Contains(x)));
```

This assumes (as do other people's solutions) that you've overridden Equals in your original object.  But if you can't override Equals for some reason, you can create an IEqualityOperator like this:

```
class EqualThingTester : IEqualityComparer<Thing>
{
    public bool Equals(Thing x, Thing y)
    {
        return x.ParentID.Equals(y.ParentID);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Thing obj)
    {
        return obj.ParentID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then the above lines become:

```
originalList.RemoveAll(x => !newList.Contains(x, new EqualThingTester()));
originalList.AddRange(newList.Where(x => !originalList.Contains(x, new EqualThingTester())));
```

And if you're passing in an IEqualityOperator anyway, you can make the second line even shorter:

```
originalList.RemoveAll(x => !newList.Contains(x, new EqualThingTester()));
originalList.AddRange(newList.Except(originalList, new EqualThingTester()));
```

Comment: Incidentally, using Except makes it even shorter, but then you have to create and pass in a custom IEqualityComparer if you're using reference types.  Which is a lot more code.

Comment: Lets say I was using reference types... and instead of ints, I was using an object that had a guid ParentId, then some other fields. How would I then go about comparing on the ParentId property of each object?

Comment: Simplest way is to override Equals.  The above lines will both use the override.  (I've tested it, and that's why I didn't use Except; it doesn't use the Equals override.)  If you *can't* override Equals, you can create an IEqualityComparer and pass it in as a second argument to Contains.

Comment: Thank you for the code sample I will try it out in my project tonite (because in fact I am using reference types, but didn't want to muck up my question and figured 'keep it simple'. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are not worried about the eventual ordering, a Hashtable/HashSet will likely be the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ solution:

```
originalList = new List<int>(
                      from x in newList
                      join y in originalList on x equals y into z
                      from y in z.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      select x);
```

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought was that you could call originalList.AddRange(newList) and then remove the duplicates - but i'm not sure if that would be any more efficient than clearing the list and repopulating it.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> firstList = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
List<int> secondList = new List<int>() {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};

List<int> newList = new List<int>();

foreach (int i in firstList)
{
  newList.Add(i);
}

foreach (int i in secondList)
{
  if (!newList.Contains(i))
  {
    newList.Add(i);
  }
}
```

Not very clean -- but it works.

Comment: Yea this is how I am doing it now, and like you, I felt it wasn't very clean and might be done easier.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way of doing this, the closest I can think of is the way DataTable handles new and deleted items.

What [@James Curran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148662/what-is-the-bestefficient-way-to-update-one-list-with-another-list#148684) suggests is merely replace the originalList object with the newList object. It will dump the oldList, but keep the variable (i.e. the pointer is still there).

Regardless, you should consider if optimising this is time well spent. Is the majority of the run time spent copying values from one list to the next, it might be worth it. If it's not, but rather some premature optimising you are doing, you should ignore it.

Spend time polishing the GUI or profile the application before you start optimising is my $.02.

Comment: Actually, I'm asking this because of persistence issues with NHibernate... Instead of ints, I have Entities representing database records. I should have reworded my title to be least amount of code instead of 'efficient' as I think that may have thrown some people off.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem developers encounter when writing UIs to maintain many-to-many database relationships. I don't know how efficient this is, but I wrote a helper class to handle this scenario:

```
public class IEnumerableDiff<T>
{
    private delegate bool Compare(T x, T y);

    private List<T> _inXAndY;
    private List<T> _inXNotY;
    private List<T> _InYNotX;

    /// <summary>
    /// Compare two IEnumerables.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x"></param>
    /// <param name="y"></param>
    /// <param name="compareKeys">True to compare objects by their keys using Data.GetObjectKey(); false to use object.Equals comparison.</param>
    public IEnumerableDiff(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y, bool compareKeys)
    {
        _inXAndY = new List<T>();
        _inXNotY = new List<T>();
        _InYNotX = new List<T>();
        Compare comparer = null;
        bool hit = false;

        if (compareKeys)
        {
            comparer = CompareKeyEquality;
        }
        else
        {
            comparer = CompareObjectEquality;
        }


        foreach (T xItem in x)
        {
            hit = false;
            foreach (T yItem in y)
            {
                if (comparer(xItem, yItem))
                {
                    _inXAndY.Add(xItem);
                    hit = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!hit)
            {
                _inXNotY.Add(xItem);
            }
        }

        foreach (T yItem in y)
        {
            hit = false;
            foreach (T xItem in x)
            {
                if (comparer(yItem, xItem))
                {
                    hit = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!hit)
            {
                _InYNotX.Add(yItem);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds and removes items from the x (current) list so that the contents match the y (new) list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x"></param>
    /// <param name="y"></param>
    /// <param name="compareKeys"></param>
    public static void SyncXList(IList<T> x, IList<T> y, bool compareKeys)
    {
        var diff = new IEnumerableDiff<T>(x, y, compareKeys);
        foreach (T item in diff.InXNotY)
        {
            x.Remove(item);
        }
        foreach (T item in diff.InYNotX)
        {
            x.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public IList<T> InXAndY
    {
        get { return _inXAndY; }
    }

    public IList<T> InXNotY
    {
        get { return _inXNotY; }
    }

    public IList<T> InYNotX
    {
        get { return _InYNotX; }
    }

    public bool ContainSameItems
    {
        get { return _inXNotY.Count == 0 && _InYNotX.Count == 0; }
    }

    private bool CompareObjectEquality(T x, T y)
    {
        return x.Equals(y);
    }

    private bool CompareKeyEquality(T x, T y)
    {
        object xKey = Data.GetObjectKey(x);
        object yKey = Data.GetObjectKey(y);
        return xKey.Equals(yKey);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your using .Net 3.5

```
var List3 = List1.Intersect(List2);
```

Creates a new list that contains the intersection of the two lists, which is what I believe you are shooting for here.